# How to send a form to own email using php?

Tags: php, forms

I am making a website with a sign-up form containing four fields (username, email, password, password repeat). I want to run a validation experiment and therefore, when someone submits the form, I want the value in the email field to get send to my own email address so I can notice him when we go live. To realize this I made a html/bootstrap page with the form and a mailer.php page with the email instructions. Here is the signup form:

```
<div class="bs-example">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
<form action="mailer.php" id="interest-form" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="username" class="form-control" id="inputUsername" placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Repeat password">
    </div>  
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
    </div>
            <button class='btn btn-signup btn-signup-sm btn-interest' id="interested" type="submit" name="remove_levels" value="delete">Sign up</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is some javascript I use to make a confirmation box pop-up asking the user if he wants to be notified when we launch and leave his email:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.btn').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();          // this line is key to preventing page reload
                             // when user clicks submit button inside form
    bootbox.confirm("Work on the game is still in progress. Submit the form and you will receive an email as soon as we launch.", function(result) {
    ("Confirm result: "+result);
                if (result > 0){
                    $('#interest-form').submit();
                };
    }); 
});
});
```

When the person clicks yes to that message he is directed to a mailer.php page that looks like this:

```
<?php

function check_input($data, $problem='')
{
    return $data;
}

function show_success($message)
{
    print_r($message);
}

function show_error($myError)
{
    print_r("error:".$myError);
}

if (!isset($_POST["submit"])) {

    $myemail = "infobetpitch@gmail.com";

    $username = check_input($_POST['inputName'], "Username");
    $email = check_input($_POST['inputEmail'], "Email");

    $subject = "Someone has sent you a message\r\n";

    $message = "Someone has sent you a message using your contac form: \r\n Username:".$username."\r\nEmail:".$email."\r\n";

    mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

    show_success($message);
    exit();
}
?>
```

Now the signup form and the bootbox confirmation work but the problem lies in sending the email address to my email. When I click on the sign up button once I put the pages on the server I get a 405: method not allowed error:

Code: MethodNotAllowed
Message: The specified method is not allowed against this resource.
ResourceType: OBJECT
Method: POST
RequestId: 0565E2E8DB90C71B
HostId: cWkoCKGeVwAWRH/X3brKzv1tTnNuQxylIPm8kd9Fid8U0vWulYB2bJz/IgoqyRvNor

Or when I click on the link through my local browser I see a white page containing the exact php code I wrote. So I was wondering the following:

- Is my mailer.php code written correctly or did I make some stupid mistake?
- I host the website through Amazon S3. Is it perhaps a problem related to the server? Do I need to do something else before this will work?

I hope someone here can identify the problem because I'm really stuck.

Thanks in advance,

Stijn

**Edit:**

I changed the code according to the suggestion done by Ole but I still get the same error message. Now my code looks like this:

```
<div class="bs-example">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
<form action="mailer.php" id="interest-form" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputUsername" value="" placeholder="Username" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="inputEmail" value="" placeholder="Email" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="inputPassword" value="" placeholder="Password" />     
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="inputPassword" value="" placeholder="Password" />
    </div>  
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox">Remember me</label>
    </div>
            <button class='btn btn-signup btn-signup-sm' id="interested">Sign up</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

And here is the code suggested by Ole:

```
<?php
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" ){

    $myemail = "infobetpitch@gmail.com";

    $username = $_POST['inputName'];
    $email = $_POST['inputEmail'];

    $subject = "Someone has sent you a message\r\n";

    $message = "Someone has sent you a message using your contac form: \r\n Username:".$username."\r\nEmail:".$email."\r\n";

    if( mail($myemail, $subject, $message) ){
        echo "Mail is sent";
    }
    else {
        echo "An error occured";
    }

    exit();
}
?>
```

I still can't get rid of that annoying error message and hope someone can help me spot my mistake.

Comment: what error are you getting

Comment: Your form doesn't appear to have any input named `submit`?

Comment: @RowlandShaw the submit part is in the javascript code: $('#interest-form').submit();

Comment: If I click the link once I have uploaded the page I see the following: 405 Method Not Allowed

Code: MethodNotAllowed
Message: The specified method is not allowed against this resource.
ResourceType: OBJECT
Method: POST
RequestId: 0565E2E8DB90C71B
HostId: cWkoCKGeVwAWRH/X3brKzv1tTnNuQxylIPm8kd9Fid8U0vWulYB2bJz/IgoqyRvN

Comment: @Stijn that submit is the method to send your request - your `$_POST` contains your post values, allow though your code does check that it's *not* set. Have you tried debugging this locally at all?

Comment: I'm completely new to php but figured it could not be too hard to make a very simple contact form. But apparently it is more complex than I thought it would be. I'll try and solve this for myself one more time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues with your code here.

**Issue #1:**
All of your input elements are missing name attributes. This is what post the value of the field to the `$_POST` array, i.e.:

```
<input type="text" name="thisistext" value="test" />
```

will create a `$_POST` array as following: `$_POST['thisistext'] = "test";`
So first off, you will have to put names to your inputs. This is basically what you have been using the id attribute for this far.

**Issue #2:**
Although this isn't a direct issue, your PHP-code contains some unnecessary functions and returns success no matter what. Firstly. change the `if( !isset( $_POST['submit'] ) )` and remove the use of `check_input()` unless you are planning to extend the function to actually do something.
Id like to suggest you to use this instead:

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" ){

        $myemail = "infobetpitch@gmail.com";

        $username = $_POST['inputName'];
        $email = $_POST['inputEmail'];

        $subject = "Someone has sent you a message\r\n";

        $message = "Someone has sent you a message using your contac form: \r\n Username:".$username."\r\nEmail:".$email."\r\n";

        if( mail($myemail, $subject, $message) ){
            echo "Mail is sent";
        }
        else {
            echo "An error occured";
        }

        exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing up the code Ole! I got previous php code from a tutorial but this looks a lot more clean and now I can better understand what the code does. But the error message is still there with the new code (See edit). Any clue on what the issue might be now? Maybe I don't pass on the post values correctly through the javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

In your file mailer.php change this:

```
 $username = $_POST['inputName'];
```

to this :

```
 $username = $_POST['inputUsername'];
```

since the posted data from the form is under the inputUsername and not under the inputName.
If for example you had a field in your form e.g

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="example" value="" placeholder="Username" />
```

in order to get the data posted from the form in this field, you will need to get this with this php code

```
$example = $_POST['example'];
```